# Probability question using fixed steps

Tags: probability

I start life at $0$, I aim to make it to $1$. I can take steps of $\dfrac{1}{2^k}, k>0$, and do so with probability  $\dfrac{1}{2^k}$.

What is the expected number of steps to reach $1$ or beyond. What is the probability I will land on $1$?

APPENDUM:

$\begin{array} {c|c}
values&expected\\
\hline
222&2\\
22N&2\\
2N2&3\\
N22&3\\
NN2&?\\
N2N&?\\
2NN&?\\
NNN&?
\end{array}$

Let $2$ be the event that we walk $\dfrac12$, and $N$ that we don't. We have $8$ outcomes, but we don't know the value of $?$, so let it be $5$ for those with one $2$, on the grounds that we will need on average $2$ more throws to 'guarantee' a $2$, and $7$ for $NNN$. So the expected value is $\dfrac{32}{8}=4$. This obviously needs some refinement.

Comment: The average length of a step if $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{4^k}=\frac{1}{3}$, hence, how many steps do you think we need to go past $1$?

Comment: @coffeemath: I believe the intending meaning is: at any time, you take a step with length $\frac{1}{2}$ toward the right with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, a step with length $\frac{1}{4}$ toward the right with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ and so on. So the OP is asking for the stopping time of a (Poisson process)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process].

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Please see my comment under karmanaut's answer.

Comment: [Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/e2ff8778b75ba09abc69) to simulate this -- the result from ten billion trials is $3.37892\pm0.00001$ for the expected number of steps and $0.379407\pm0.000005$ for the probability.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be the the distance travelled in the $i^{th}$ step. Then, $E(X_i)$ = ${1 \over {2^2}} + {1 \over {4^2}} + {1 \over {8^2}} + .. = {1 \over 3} $. The expected distance travelled in $n$ steps is $E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} E(X_i) = {n \over 3}$. Can you take this hint and try to come up with the answer?

As for the probability of ever reaching exactly $1$, let us do it the traditional counting way. Let $P_i$ be the probability of reaching 1 in exactly $i$ steps. Then $P_1=0, P_2={1 \over 4}, P_3 = {3}{1 \over 2}{1 \over 4}{1 \over 4}, P_4 = {4.3}{1 \over 2}{1 \over 4}{1 \over 8}{1 \over 8} + {1 \over 4}{1 \over 4}{1 \over 4}{1 \over 4}$. So a good lower bound would be 0.25 but I can't think of a way to generate $P_i$ in the usual way. Maybe a recursive formulation can help.

Comment: Still leaves the other question, about probability of ever landing on *exactly* 1.

Comment: The expected number of steps is not in general the reciprocal of the expected step length. Consider step $0$ with probability $0.999$ and step $1000$ with probability $.001$. The expected step length is $1$, but the expected number of steps is clearly greater than $1$.

Comment: @joriki Your example is a geometric distribution with p = 0.001. So expected number of steps should be ${1 \over p} = 1000$. But can we generalize this to the question OP discussed where state changes are mandatory? Because if yes, we can very easily model the problem as a recursive markov chain.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that last sentence. Are you disputing that my example invalidates your hint?

Comment: I am not contesting my hint. It is clearly wrong. Extending your example, if step 1 is with probability 0.999 and step 1000 with probability 0.001, then the expected step length is 1.999 ~ 2 but the expected number of steps is clearly 1. I wanted to ask in which situation we can say that expected number of steps is equal to reciprocal of the expected step length.

Comment: I don't actually know any way to characterize that situation.

Comment: In your $P_4$, the factor should be $4\cdot3$ instead of $4$, for $4$ choices to place $\frac12$ and then $3$ to place $\frac14$.

Comment: i think the problem with your hint is that the problem doesn't allow a 1/3rd of a step - it's like asking you to throw a 3.5 with a normal dice

Comment: @karmanaut; i think its compositions of 2^(k-1) into powers of two and k parts